# Cloudfront, Compression, HTTPS Load error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, routes, amazon-cloudfront

I've working on a project and we recently switched from HTTP to HTTPS.
So here are a few things. We're hosting our website on S3 with the static website enabled. For the server, we created an instance through Elastic Beanstalk. Using ACM, we have a certificate and successfully attached it to our frontend through Cloudfront and our server through Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer.

Now our site is finally live and says secure! For some reason sometimes on the first load it takes upwards of 10 seconds to load the page and usually ends of timing out. This happens every couple of hours or whenever we clear our cache. But as soon as we refresh the site takes 2-3 seconds to load and everything works perfectly. We think that this is because we're using Angular 5 and using ng build, we get a large file called vendor.bundle.js that's around 13 mb.

We want to gzip this to hopefully solve the problem cause we think the website is timing out before that vendor file is even loaded in. We went into Cloudfront and enabled compression. We then went into our S3 bucket and added "Content-Length" as an allowed header. I looked up the request and response body and it is as follows:

```
Request
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: riftapp.io
:path: /vendor.bundle.js
Host: riftapp.io
If-None-Match: "de078424bf26a6b1e2873009a37924ee-2"
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Cookie: __stripe_mid=333bb2df-0b1a-4757-a193-0596baeabd7c;  
   __stripe_sid=bff74933-d3fd-4ee2-a7a8-e5e73a224fdb
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4)
    AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1      
Safari/605.1.15
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 25 Jul 2018 03:02:42 GMT
Referer: https://riftapp.io/home

Response
:status: 304
Via: 1.1 e3a844a9e0d478ce4d12c6d1f3a2d892.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
ETag: "de078424bf26a6b1e2873009a37924ee-2"
Age: 3021
Date: Wed, 25 Jul 2018 03:55:47 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-cf-id: JHS0o-e-tBh1wfTy4AgKHALzHEEvdbUOkO0mgzSc56LAmnx515WS9A==
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

We think that maybe it's because the request body host is riftapp.io instead of abc.cloudfront.net or something, but when I tried to delete the origin, I can't because our S3 bucket is linked to it.

Comment: What error are you actually getting? 304 is not an error response, it basically just says your browser already have the newest version. Try disabling caching in your browser when testing (Chrome has a setting for this in its dev tools).

Comment: Also, it seems like riftapp.io is pointing to S3 and not Cloudfront. So it won't matter what cloudfront settings you have.

Comment: I figured it out thanks! My file was too big to be compressed so I figured out a way to take it down a bit before compressing. For some reason our problem is still there though, where the web page fails for some reason, but then works perfectly for the next few minutes. Not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: No real idea why it would intermittently not work. Do you know which requests fail? Have you changed to point it to Cloudfront instead of S3?

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand the question. What do you mean point at Cloudfront? In my route 53 I did configure that. The link is https://riftapp.io if you would like to check it out. It may work for you the first try but sometimes it just stops working and times out.

Comment: Nevermind the S3 thing. That seemed to have been the earlier Route 53 config. Now it looks correct. Not sure why it would sometimes not work though, loads fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help by the way, it's awesome that you're so responsive! Originally we thought that it was because one of our bundles was 13mb, but I was able to compress it to 600kb so it runs super quickly now. However, we can't seem to trace why it doesn't load sometimes on https because it seems random and after it times out, it usually reloads and works or just works the next time. 

Could it be because we're using the free tier Elastic Beanstalk servers? If we were to upgrade could that help?

Comment: Depending on how many users, i guess you might be overloading the Elastic Beanstalk, but the monitoring on that should show it. You can try and enable logging for Cloudfront and look at those logs.